# Каким образом на сервере можно отключить клиентов на основе их региональной принадлежности?

Tags: сервер, ip

Где можно взять диапазоны IP адресов, те что принадлежат определённым государствам, например, России? Я бы хотел использовать эту информацию для определения страны-источника комментариев: он из Китая, США и т.п.

Мой сайт предназначен исключительно для жителей России (физически находящихся в России) и я хотел бы ограничить к нему доступ из других стран.

Comment: 1. Не все русскоговорящие живут в России. 2. Не все живущие в России находятся под российскими IP. 3. Вам должно быть стыдно.

Comment: @Athari: Почему столько минусов? Не считая слога, абсолютно резонный вопрос. Мало ли из каких соображений автор вопроса хочет ограничить доступ к его серверу определённой страной. Задача вполне легитимна

Comment: @IgorChubin Постановка вопроса в форме "заколебали" не располагает к положительной оценке. Ну и Интернет в России переживает печальные времена, поэтому вопрос может быть болезненным.

Comment: @Athari: Я изменил стиль вопроса, но нужно чтобы кто-то разрешил моё изменение

Comment: Народ объясню сразу зачем мне ограничить доступ! Сайт посвящен патриотам России =) И когда к примеру тролли из других стран  отписываются в комментах это печаль, т.к. это начинает заводить всех и начинается грызня, оскорбления и т.д. Естественно про тему все забыли и пишут всякую фигню. Далее - разные рекламные сообщения. Модерирование занимает много времени и нервов. Вот и возникла мысль, что для каждой страны выделен диапазон айпи адресов, вот они мне и нужны! Надеюсь "минусовщикам" понятно?

Comment: Есть одно добавление для iptables, называется ipset. Очень удобная штука для таких целей, правда она внезапно написана американцами для финской операционной системы, которая использует английский протокол http для доставки информации, наверное будет не очень патриотично все это использовать.

Comment: @FrancNet: Прежде всего, давайте будем вежливыми. Нервная обстановка на SO не способствует конструктивным обсуждениям. Затем, по вашей проблеме. Если человек с деструктивным поведением захочет зайти на ваш сайт, то он обойдёт ограничение по IP (например, через прокси, хотя это требует определённой технической грамотности), так что вам всё равно нужны живые модераторы на сайте. А по технической стороне вопроса смотрите ответы.

Comment: @FrancNet, держите себя в руках и проявляйте уважение к сообществу StackOverflow. Здесь тоже могут быть участники из разных стран.

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны определить список автономных систем, которые вы считаете российскими.
Затем на основе этого найти список префиксов входящих в эти автономные системы.
Дальше можно по каждому адресу определить, есть ли он в числе разрешённых префиксов или нет.

Другой способ (основывающийся по сути на этом методе): использовать готовые библиотеки, определяющие принадлежность стране по IP-адресу.

Например, для Python:

- http://pythonhosted.org/python-geoip/

Comment: Зайдя на статистику Яндекса по моему сайту я вижу статистику посещений по странам. Значит Яндекс может 100% определить с какой страны зашел пользователь! Вот и возникла идея ограничить посещение для некоторых стран. А где взять диапазоны IP адресов я не могу найти. Вернее есть куски но не полные.

Comment: @FrancNet: я же скинул ссылку на готовую библиотеку, таких десятки, и для самых разных языков

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое: ограничение по IP на вэб-сервере. К сожалению, вы не уточнили в вопросе, какой вэб-сервер вы используете; если, допустим, это Nginx, то можно использовать GeoIP модуль. Описывать настройки не буду, ибо документации в интернете полно. Попробуйте, например:

- https://admins.su/nginxgeoip-blokiruem-dostup-k-sajtu-na-nginx-polzovatelyam-iz-nezhelatelnyx-stran/
- https://www.google.ru/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=nginx+geoip&gws_rd=cr&ei=v-iWWLfbGcGSsAHx9I34CA